# Process with a certain stack size?

Tags: c#, .net, process, stack

Is there a way in C# to start a process with a certain stack size?

Comment: This begs the question: *"Why do you care what size the stack is for a given process?"* Is there some reason you feel you need to change the default behavior of the application?

Comment: Perhaps he uses stackalloc[...] a lot for graphics-intensive stuff or is unable to tail-optimize recursive calls in large trees but still want the recursive version and not the stack based version of the code? Stranger things have happened.

Comment: @Henrik: perhaps we should ask the OP, and actually find out instead of guessing?

Comment: @lbushkin - I get this problem flood-filling a large area with a recursive method. So easy to code, an easy stack size increase would have been a cool way to keep the 5 minute version. Unfortunately this is an unacceptable PITA to increase stack size. Refactored to use 'the stack based version of the code'. Another 15 minutes of my life and more than doubled the method size. BTW: BOOO to the OP for not saying WHY they need more stack space. DOUBLE BOO to you for assuming they didn't have a good reason and were just being stupid!

Answer (score 4):

A down-voting fest, I hesitate to post.  But Henrik is right, the very first thread is started by Windows when it launches the EXE.  It does a whole bunch of work, loading the CLR is one of its duties.  And it runs the Main() method in your program.

The .NET framework gives very few options to configure that thread.  Only the [MTAThread] and [STAThread] attributes on the Main() method makes a difference, they affect how the CLR calls the CoInitializeEx() API function.

The stack size of the thread is in fact configurable.  It is one of the fields in the PE32 file format, the format used in Windows for executable images.  Usually the C# or VB.NET compiler is responsible for generating that file, neither have an option to set the initial thread stack size.  Bit of an oversight.  They use defaults, one megabyte for a 32-bit EXE, four megabytes for a 64-bit EXE (Platform Target = x64).

Changing that value is possible, you can run the Editbin.exe utility to modify the EXE file, use the /STACK command line option.  You'll want to do this in a post-build step.  Beware that this is incompatible with strong names or signing with a certificate since it modifies the EXE file.

It isn't a real problem btw, if you need a thread with a lot of stack space then you create one yourself in the Main() method.

Answer (score 0):

In this thread they show a PoC that you can use Editbin.exe to modify the default stack size of the thread that enters main:
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/229335-stack-size

and if you spawn new threads, there's an API for it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149581.aspx

Comment: -1: he asked about a process, and please don't post answers that are nothing but links.